# How to migrate Maven Release Plugin to from SVN to Git?

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin

We are in the process of moving our projects from SVN to Git. We use Maven Release Plugin to `mvn release:prepare` and `mvn release:perform` our packages.

Along with that, we are modifying the pom.xml file scm properties to point to our git repositories.

However, we get the following error when we run `mvn release:prepare` :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.1:prepare (default-cli) on project MyProject: Unable to check for local modifications
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The svn command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] 'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[ERROR] operable program or batch file.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Why is it still attempting to execute `cmd.exe /X /C "svn --non-interactive status"` ?
What else needs to be configured to fully migrate over this release process?

My pom.xml details for context:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:https://myGitProjectUrl.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://myGitProjectUrl.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://myGitProjectUrl</url>
</scm>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Maven Release Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <goals>deploy</goals>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Can you please confirm if you are in a correct git project and pom file with git scm URL?

Comment: @RishikeshDarandale, good question. Yes I've triple checked now just to make sure. I'm running the command from within the local folder containing the pom.xml, the folder is the correct project and matches the appropriate git repo.

Comment: hmmm everything looks good. Can you please try updating the plugin version to `2.5.3`?

Comment: Please define the maven-release-plugin in pluginManagement and not just you did...Apart from that are you trying to call it from command line or from a CI solution like Jenkins ? Working on windows/linux ? Please show the full log output of the run...and yes btw. try to use 2.5.3 of the maven-release-plugin...

Comment: Do any module POMs contain <scm> blocks with svn URLs? Is there release plugin config in any parent of the POM displayed in the question?

Comment: @user944849 I just confirmed that no other pom.xml files in this project have scm properties declared. The only ones are contained within the parent pom, which all reference the git repos.

Comment: Can you show the full pom file or put on github as example project so we can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

you can try below `plugin` with `maven-invoker` dependency :

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.1</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-invoker</artifactId>
              <version>2.2</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: The the dependency is already part of the maven-release-plugin no need to define it another time...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I recently came across the same problem and many others are likely to follow.

I ran `release:prepare` prior to adding my scm. By default the plugin will use svn. After adding the scm for git I re-ran `release:prepare` and it will always continue from the previous failed point.

Try running `mvn release:prepare -Dresume=false` this will start the release process and attempt to use git.